# Query regarding solving a exact differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals

Why do we have to rewrite the equation for reducing the power of $\cos x$ term? Instead why we can't leave as it is and then answer will change because there won't be any extra $\dfrac 12$. Since the rule says do not integrate the terms containing $x$. So technically $\cos^2 x$ is in $x$ term, so why cant we leave it as it is and proceed?

See the image attached for reference.
[image]

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) + [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the $cos ^2 x$ term  and proceed this is fine but in the book they linerise the $\cos ^2 x$ term because it's easier to differentiate $\cos (2x)$ and check that the DE is exact.
$$\partial_y M=\partial_x N$$
You can keep and  differentiate $\cos^2 x$ and check the exactness condition:
$$\partial_x N=-\partial_x \cos^2 x=2\cos x \sin x=\sin 2x=\partial_yN$$
Both methods are fine.